# copy formula to many cells in excel

Tags: excel

Hi i want to copy the formula in some continous cells in same column

the formula is

```
=IF(L4>27,Complexity!B10,IF(L4>24,Complexity!B9,IF(L4>20,Complexity!B8,IF(L4>17,Complexity!B7,IF(L4>14,Complexity!B6,IF(L4>10,Complexity!B5,IF(L4>7,Complexity!B4,IF(L4>4,Complexity!B3,Complexity!B2))))))))
```

if iam using fill handle for the cells below the formula will change to 
like below

```
=IF(L5>27,Complexity!B11,IF(L5>24,Complexity!B10,IF(L5>20,Complexity!B9,IF(L5>17,Complexity!B8,IF(L5>14,Complexity!B7,IF(L5>10,Complexity!B6,IF(L5>7,Complexity!B5,IF(L5>4,Complexity!B4,Complexity!B3))))))))

=IF(L6>27,Complexity!B12,IF(L6>24,Complexity!B11,IF(L6>20,Complexity!B10,IF(L6>17,Complexity!B9,IF(L6>14,Complexity!B8,IF(L6>10,Complexity!B7,IF(L6>7,Complexity!B6,IF(L6>4,Complexity!B5,Complexity!B4))))))))

etc..
```

but i want the Complexity!B* value as it is in parent formula

Comment: Use `Complexity!$B$8` if you want both the row (8th) and column (B) to be fixed.

Comment: put a $ in front of the row numbers in your formula in the places where you don't want the row to increment when you drag it down

Comment: To add to what @shahkalpesh pressing F4 while highlighting the range will cycle the options (saves typing so many dollar signs)

Comment: thanks shahkalpesh it's working

Answer (score 0):

You can use $ to make the column/row fixed. So it will be B$10 ... B$9... in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Just fix all you b with $ sign as in here:

```
=IF(L4>27,Complexity!$B$10,IF(L4>24,Complexity!$B$9,IF(L4>20,Complexity!$B$8,IF(L4>17,Complexity!$B$7,IF(L4>14,Complexity!$B$6,IF(L4>10,Complexity!$B$5,IF(L4>7,Complexity!$B$4,IF(L4>4,Complexity!$B$3,Complexity!$B$2))))))))
```

A $ sign before the letter fixes the column while $ sign before the number fixes the row.

Then you can drag this with no problems..